# Open AI: Remember the last conversation

Tags: flutter, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am following one course on Udemy, to make a ChatGPT kind of app in Flutter. In the given below code, I want the bot to remember the last conversation.

**For example**
user: explain AI
bot: Artificial intelligence...
user: explain as if I am 5 years old
bot: Artificial Intelligence...

**CODE**

```
 import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../api_key.dart';

class APIService
{
  Future<http.Response> requestOpenAI(String userInput, String mode, int maximumTokens) async
  {
    const String url = "https://api.openai.com/";
    final String openAiApiUrl = mode == "chat" ? "v1/completions" : "v1/images/generations";

    final body = mode == "chat"
        ?
    {
      "model": "text-davinci-003",
      "prompt": userInput,
      "max_tokens": 2000,
      "temperature": 0.9,
      "n": 1,
    }
        :
    {
      "prompt": userInput,
    };

    final responseFromOpenAPI = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url + openAiApiUrl),
      headers:
      {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer $apiKey"
      },
      body: jsonEncode(body),
    );

    return responseFromOpenAPI;
  }
}
```

Given above is the code, I actually tried my best but all I got is **NoSuchMethodError**. I'll be really thankful if you could help me with it. All I am looking for is that bot should remember the previous conversation,

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Currently there is no error, All I want is that bot should remember the previous conversations. But when I changed the code, or tried to modify it then I was getting NoSuchMethodError

Comment: Where - at which line - did you get the NoSuchMethodError?

Comment: I got this...

I/flutter (26182): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (26182): Receiver: null
I/flutter (26182): Tried calling: [](0)

Comment: any update on how we can custom open ai plugin so it remember the last conversations.

for example if we say "my favourite color is blue" and then ask "what is my favourite color" it should say "blue is your favourite color"

many thanks